# Office Add-in to add template to Word

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am trying to create an add-in for Word to add a template based on Word file saved as `.xml`.

What I am doing is I am creating my template using Word 2016. The template contains Body, header and footer. Then I am saving the Word file as Word XML Document (`.xml`)

Then in my VS project I am using the following code to add the template to blank Word file:

```js
var myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myXML;
myOOXMLRequest.open('GET', fileName, false);
myOOXMLRequest.send();

if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {
    myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
}

Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myXML, {
    coercionType: 'ooxml'
});
```

My problem is that the body of my template is added correctly to the new one but the headers and footers are not there.

I am new to `ooxml` and office.js. Any advice will be great on how to add the header and footer from a file with the body directly.

Answer (score 1):

To use templates in Office.js you need to base64 encode the .dotx template file (upload it to base64encode.org and save the txt file). Once you have the .txt file, you add it to your project and tell Word to create a new document from that and it will include headers/footers/styles from that template:

```
this.http.get('./assets/template.txt').subscribe(response => {
  Word.run(async context => {
    const myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(response);
    context.load(myNewDoc);
    await context.sync();
    myNewDoc.open();
    await context.sync();
  });
});
```

Comment: I am not convinced that this approach will work with Office online, opening a new document in a new tab  is not supported.

Comment: that actually works fine apart from the add-in asking for permission before creating the new document where the desktop version creates the document without any popups.

Answer (score 0):

The [document.setSelectedDataAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync) method will only affect the body of the document. This is because Word is using your current cursor position as the insertion point. In other words, it is the equivalent of manually pasting into the Word document (which would also not alter your headers or footers).

You can get a lot more granular with the host-specific Word API. This newer API has support for managing [Sections](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/section) (header, footer, body). Once you have a Section, you can then use [insertOOXML()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#insertooxmlooxml-string-insertlocation-insertlocation) to insert your content.